# C++ Function pointer to a method from an unknown class

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, bind

My question is, how can a class get a pointer to a method from an unknown class. I tried to do this with std::function and std::bind but it didn't work well. here's what iv'e done (with a simplified example):

```
class Baz
{
public:
   Baz(function<void()> requiredFunc) : mFuncPtr(requiredFunc) {}

   void doSomethingWithPtr()
   {
      mFuncPtr();
   }

private:
   function<void()> mFuncPtr;
};

class Foo
{
public:
   void someFunc() { cout << "Hello World"; }
};

int main()
{
   Foo* foo = new Foo();
   auto funcPtr = std::bind(&Foo::someFunc, foo);

   Baz* baz = new Baz(funcPtr);
   baz->doSomethingWithPtr(); // Crashes here
}
```

This code **compiles**, however **crashes in runtime**, the bind does not seem to work for some reason.

**Thanks in advance :)**

Comment: I don't see any problems in this code, and I'm unable to reproduce the crash. I'd recommend learning how to use gdb or another debugger to acquire a stack trace, which is invaluable in solving these kinds or problems.

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b13348c609cdb3d)

Comment: Perhaps, in the larger program where you're experiencing the crash, you've freed `foo` before you've called `baz->doSomethingWithPtr()`? Or put `foo` in a local variable (like: `Foo foo;`) and then used `baz` after that function returns? Either way, the problem is likely to be to do with the lifetime of the objects you're using, rather than the general idea of `std::bind` and `std::function` this way.

Comment: looks like you guys are right and the simplified version of the code that I brought here does not reproduce the issue. i will update the post once i figure out what is going on.